# how to find programatically that dll is injected into some process or not using c#

Tags: c#-3.0

**i have to inject a dll into some process .now i want that after injection how to find that dll is injected without using any third party tools**

**strong text**

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you are asking? The above statement is not helping to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is get all assemblies that reference the start up assembly by using `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()` all the way don't till you've got all referenced assemblies and compare that with all loaded assemblies in the current AppDomain, by using `AppDomain.Current.GetAssemblies()`.